# mysql not encoding characters properly in bash

Tags: mysql, bash, utf-8

I have a bash script which reads data from a DB. I am trying to get the character set to `UTF-8` because the result produced from the script is "Heemw?i" when it should be "Heemwéi". There seems to be an encoding issue, even with `--default-character-set=utf8`. 
I still do not get the correct result, can someone please advise.

```
QUERY="select name from my_table"

MY_ROW=`mysql -sN -u$USER -p$PWD --default-character-set=utf8  -h$HOST  mydb   -e  "$QUERY"`
```

**Expected result** : Heemwéi

**Actual result** : Heemw?i

thanks in advance

Comment: Is your console/terminal set up to handle UTF-8 correctly...? Is the value in the database stored correctly?

Comment: i have #!/bin/bash at the top and echo Heemwéi works fine, data in the source DB is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed the issue by by wrapping the column around function CONVERT e.g. select CONVERT(name USING utf8) from my_table

Comment: If this works, it may be an indication that your data is ***not*** "fine" in the database.

Comment: Phrased another way:  sometimes "two wrongs make a right".

Answer (score 0):

`SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- you will probably find that the column is not `CHARACTER SET utf8`, like it should be.

Please provide `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ... WHERE ...` so we can see how the data is stored.

`é`, in latin1 is hex `c9`; in utf8: `c389`.

Assuming that the table is mistakenly declared latin1, and it actually has latin1 bytes in it, then this is how to 'fix' it:

A table declared to be latin1, and containing latin1 bytes can be converted to utf8 via

```
ALTER TABLE tbl CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```